# How to create an Index of changes to product data

Tags: descriptive-statistics, business-intelligence

Firstly - I'm a developer with a very limited knowledge of stats / math - so, be gentle.

I have a dataset of product categories, and data about each of them, for each day:

```
1 June 2015
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦═══════════════════╦════════════════════╗
║  Category  ║ Average-price ║ Average-Discount% ║ Number-of-products ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬═══════════════════╬════════════════════╣
║ Hats       ║            12 ║                33 ║                214 ║
║ Trousers   ║            44 ║                40 ║                228 ║
║ Sunglasses ║            77 ║                15 ║                411 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩═══════════════════╩════════════════════╝
```

Somehow, I want to give an indication of when the best time to purchase from any category would be, with the broad assumption being that the best day is when:

"There's the highest discount, most products, and the lowest price"

Essentially, I wish to create a baseline "sales index" (baseline 100?) and have it track each day as the data changes, and be able to report on the index:

"The Sunglasses index is +10 today" - a good time to buy sunglasses

"The Hats index is -5 today" - don't buy a hat today

I appreciate this may all sound a bit weird & nebulous - but I hope you understand what I'm trying to create.

Any ideas are most welcome.

Comment: How many categories do you have? And are you trying to maximize or optimize a consumer-oriented function or a firm-oriented, profit function?

Comment: About 1000 categories - however, I wish to have each one calculated independently - so, the above example is 3 'indices' actually. Consumer orientated - so, the data doesn't have to be rock-solid or anything.

Comment: Assuming *nonindependence* of the categories may be leveragable in building your "index," particularly when they are economically related, e.g., purchase of a suit can be tied to purchases of ties, belts, and other accessories. How many days of information do you have?

Comment: I want this index to dynamically update daily - and in a rolling manner - so, maybe relative to the last year of data for example? Imagine a 'stock market' style graph detailing the 'index' of sunglasses for example

Comment: The most commonly used metric in retail sales is *Year Ago Sales* compared with current sales. So, yes, one year of data at a minimum. If you want to track seasonality, e.g., sales spikes during holidays, then you would need at least two years of data to calibrate an annual index. Finally, do you want some simple heuristic as an index or a statistical model? This is like asking how this index is going to be used.

Comment: Yeah, sure - although I'm more interested in looking at these specific metric to calculate some kind of index - not raw sales data - I think some simple heuristic would do...

Comment: A good example would be this, actually: https://www.reed.co.uk/recruiter/jobindex - they use Number of jobs and average salary by sector

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30784/discussion-between-djohnson-and-dave-bish).